# how to open backend window and manipulate data in frontend pages more efficiently than an ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax

how to open backend window and manipulate data in frontend pages more efficiently than an ajax request?

i.e. in the page you are, clicking on "modify" as a logged user, it will appear a window with background opacity(similiar to a popup or an ajax) starting editing content and onclick "publish" or "modify" in that area, the content will be send to database and when done page reload...

it it possible to do this without using ajax response over ajax response?

thanks in adv.

Comment: The behavior you described is a text-book case of an AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) operation. What do you mean by "similar to a popup or an ajax"?.

Comment: i mean exactly what you told...i was considering ajax writing this post, but ajax response over ajax responses as described has a slow execution time i think...it is not fast and i'm asking me how to speed up that kind of system (using ajax or not - if there are other way or not) ...

Comment: have you ever seen duckduckgo.com? look at that site and clicking on the "3 horizontal lines" on the right and "change background color" clicking by color circles. Does it is ajax? when you change background color, is an ajax response?? i don't know but it effects will be applied very faster

Comment: and the Admin toolbar of Drupal7? it has many functionalities loading their contents in the window as i would like to...response over responses i think...but its system is very faster so i doubt. How to may i implement something similar without too much delay?

Comment: I extensively use AJAX to load entire pages in my CMS engine without reloading the whole thing even once. The response from the remote webserver is so fast that I have to manually add some delay for the loading animations to complete; the request itself completes under 50ms most of the time.

I'm sure duckduckgo.com uses preloaded styles, although an AJAX call would be just that fast.

AJAX is not a library, it's a procedure using native JavaScript tools. This is similar to asking an alternative to arrays or objects. Although you might read: http://www.jscripters.com/alternatives-to-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, I recommend the following article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

**AJAX** (acronym of Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) is not a library or function that you just call and everything is done automatically. It is a programming concept composed of a collection of native Javascript instructions to interchange data between a client and a server, as you no doubt know it.

"Without using AJAX" would imply the need for an alternative similar to "alternative of looping through an array". You see where that goes.

If you'd really like, you could build up your own concept based on **XMLHttpRequest**, but it should be unnecessary unless you are dealing with horrendous amounts of data and need serious shortcuts.  **XMLHttpRequest** is the part that is responsible for the data-exhange itself.

The ***perceived* response speed** of a simple AJAX request depends primarily on:

1. The time it takes for the server to execute your request
2. The time it takes for the request to reach the server, plus the time for its reverse
3. The duration of client-side processing before and/or after the request.

If you think your AJAX is very slow, you might want analyze your code to find possible spots for improvement. A possible example might be combining multiple requests that happen at the same time into a larger one.

Comment: Good! This is just what i was looking for. probably there are bugs in my code. it skill over 300ms to keep responses. Thank you